# Jquery check checkbox before change event's proccess done

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an event :

```
$(document).on('change', '.many-checkbox', function() {
  doSomething()
});
```

`doSomething()` is kinda heavy, so checkbox with class `many-checkbox` will have a delay before they actually being checked/uncheck.

I want to remove those delays.

So, how do we check/uncheck it before `doSomething()` is done ?.

thanks.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in StackSnippet/JSFiddle? Looks like the problem could be somewhere else. Or in `doSomething`.

Comment: BTW, `$(this).prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));` does NOTHING but adds delay.

Comment: I'm sure the problem is in `doSomething`, that's why i want to bypass it. So, make the checkbox checked/uncheck manually even before `doSomething` is done.

Comment: Yeah, I know my solution is kinda ridiculous. I've removed it.

Comment: Can doSomething be made asynchronous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replacr `doSomething()` function to `setTimout` method. For example:

```
$(document).on('change', '.many-checkbox', function() {
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    // do something
  }, 100);
});
```

In result the JavaScript execution will be paused to let the rendering threads catch up.

Comment: Why? And how will it make the function execute faster?

Comment: @Tushar, this will not be faster. But it will be executed after another actions. I'm sorry, but I do not remember a source of this solution.

Comment: @Tushar, I find [the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/779785/7914637) that answers to your question.

Comment: Ah, i see. It means wait for 0.01 second before do `doSomething()`, resulting the checkbox being checked first between 0.01 second. Its not making it faster, but it bypass the proccess by 0.01 second.

Comment: @MarcelAngir, also you can try to use `0` timeout value. But in my case I was needed to use positive value of timout.

Comment: thank you very much @Alexander

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there's all sorts of wrong going on here but you could start by not listening to any change within the entire body and filtering down to the .many-checkbox class.

Listen directly to changes to the checkboxes:

```
$('.many-checkbox').on('change', function() {
  doSomething();
});
```

If you show us what doSomething is doing, we could maybe make it asynchronous.

Comment: I'm sorry, its way to complicated to be made async. As you say, there's a lot of mistake on it, my bad code ~ But thank you very much for your answer, appreciate it so much.